# References to methods C#

Tags: c#, python, functional-programming

I'm just wondering if there is a C# equivilent for this python code.
I want to store the names of methods in some sort of collection and call them later on. I have searched, but I really don't know what to look for.

For example in python I could do:

```
def add_one(x):
  return x + 1
def double_it(x):
  return x*2

maths_rules = [add_one, double_it]
def do_maths(maths_rules, x):
  for func in maths_rules:
    x = func(x)
  return x

print do_maths(maths_rules, 9)
# >>> 20
```

This is a silly example, but you should get the idea.

Comment: I should have mentioned I am on .NET 3.5. Not sure if this matters for the solutions below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use delegates. For this one use `Func<int, int>`.
like:

```
int addone(int x)
{
    return x + 1;
}
```

and in main:

```
Func<int, int> myFunc = new Func<int, int>(addone);
myFunc(5); // to use it, you can pass it as you like
```

example on your code:

```
static int add_one(int x)
{
    return x + 1;
}
static int double_it(int x)
{
    return x * 2;
}
static int do_maths(List<Func<int, int>> math_rules, int x)
{
    foreach(var func in math_rules)
        x = func(x);
    return x;
}
static void Main(string[] Args)
{
    List<Func<int, int>> math_rules = new List<Func<int, int>>();
    math_rules.Add(new Func<int, int>(add_one));
    math_rules.Add(new Func<int, int>(double_it));
    Console.WriteLine(do_maths(math_rules, 9)); // 20
}
```

or use lambdas as suggested in comment:

```
static int do_maths(List<Func<int, int>> math_rules, int x)
{
    foreach(var func in math_rules)
        x = func(x);
    return x;
}
static void Main(string[] Args)
{
    List<Func<int, int>> math_rules = new List<Func<int, int>>();
    math_rules.Add(new Func<int, int>((x) => (x + 1)));
    math_rules.Add(new Func<int, int>((x) => (x * 2)));
    Console.WriteLine(do_maths(math_rules, 9)); // 20
}
```

Comment: or use a lambda `Func<int, int> add_one = (x) => x + 1;`

Answer (score 7):

You are looking for [delegates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171.aspx).

> A delegate is a type that defines a method signature. When you instantiate a delegate, you can associate its instance with any method with a compatible signature. You can invoke 
>   (or call) the method through the delegate instance.

Your example in C#, using the [Func<T, TResult> Delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx):

```
int add_one(int x) { return x + 1; }
int double_it(int x) { return x * 2; }

var maths_rules = new List<Func<int,int>> { add_one, double_it };

int do_maths(IEnumerable<Func<int,int>> maths_rules, int x)
{
    foreach (var func in maths_rules)
    {
        x = func(x);
    }
    return x;
}

Console.WriteLine(do_maths(maths_rules, 9));
// prints "20"
```